# How to best implement HTTPS with Node.js for all connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm building a stateless authentication by Double Submit Cookie in Node.js/ExpressJs and wonder how I best can make all my connections go over HTTPS.

The reason is that I want to be able to handle high traffic and only use HTTPS for security reasons with the stateless authentication.

1. Should I avoid the HTTPS npm dependency and set up a reverse proxy server in Nginx?
2. Perhaps I can configure Nginx so that it will enforce HTTPS without doing any other in-app settings in ExpressJs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the built-in [`https`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/https.html) module that comes with Node.js (not an npm module). This will handle the HTTPS requests. Good for light applications, personal web sites, development.
2. Set up a proxy (nginx, HAProxy, etc.) in front of your Web server (which uses [`http`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html) module). The proxy will terminate SSL from an incoming HTTPS request, then proxy a plain HTTP request to your Web server. Good for production, high traffic applications that also need load balancing provided by these proxy software.

For playing around, I suggest going simple with the built-in `https` module. I suppose you do not expect millions of requests to introduce a proxy to your stack.

Comment: Actually I do. That is why I want to implement Double Submit Cookie as a stateless authentication for performance reasons. Why do you say that the proxy will terminate SSL? I want the server to enforce HTTPS for all connections. I need some resource to study up on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: @DarkCodeWiz, you listed 2 options and they propose the same thing: use nginx instead of built-in HTTPS feature of Node.js. If you want that, it's called SSL Termination which I mentioned in my option 2. If you really want to secure all your connections even local communication between multiple hosts and even processes, then go with HTTPS module inside Node.js. For performance reason, I would suggest any kind of proxy like nginx which will terminate SSL and distribute the load between multiple processes of your HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you kindly again. I will implement you answer the best I can and update what I did here later on as an answer.